# Getting close matches from custom search engine in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm using the newest version of Codeigniter.

So I'm building a clan database and you can search the database by picking from dropdowns and it'll show the results. That part is working, however I want to have it pull results that are Close Matches to what they searched for if there are no results.

Im a little new to this so please go easy... I'm not sure how to exactly to do this part. Here's what I have so far.

```
public function search_clans(){

    $platform = $this->input->post('platform');
    $timezone = $this->input->post('timezone');
    $age_group = $this->input->post('age_group');
    $playstyle = $this->input->post('playstyle');
    $gamemode = $this->input->post('gamemode');

    $this->db->where('platform', $platform);
    $this->db->where('timezone', $timezone);
    $this->db->where('age_group', $age_group);
    $this->db->where('playstyle', $playstyle);
    $this->db->where('gamemode', $gamemode);

    $query = $this->db->get('clans');
    return $query->result_array();

}
```

It works if a clan exists with all the fields chosen. But how can I have it find matches if a couple of the DB Wheres don't match?

Comment: What you need is `$this->db->or_where('timezone', $timezone);` etc - https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data

Comment: thanks yeah I was checking out the where or, can I use that in conjunction with where and? because if the person is searching for players on the PC platform I wouldnt show xbox and ps4 results, but I could show clans that match in different timezones and play different gamemodes.

Comment: in that case you would probably be better off writing a custom where statement like this: `$where = "platform='$platform' AND (timezone='$timezone' OR age_group='$age_group'";
$this->db->where($where);` either that approach or get creative with if/else conditions to wrap your where clauses in conditions to match your logic

Comment: ahhh gotcha thanks man, that makes sense, I only have 6 dropsdowns they can choose from so I could just write out results for the different combinations. That makes sense, THANKS!